# Alternate measures in a repeating passage

Tags: notation, sheet-music, repeats

I've a nine measure passage that repeats with an exception of one measure.  So the 1st run plays measure 2A and 2nd run plays measure 2B.  Is there notation that indicates this? Or will I have to write out both 9 measure passages with the correct measure 2?

Comment: Related: [Is the volta ONLY used to mark unique end of a section or can it mark unique verse content within a section?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/120963/is-the-volta-only-used-to-mark-unique-end-of-a-section-or-can-it-mark-unique-ver)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1st & 2nd time repeats - thanks to [Wikipedia - Repeat Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeat_sign) for the image...

[image]

So you score your first 8 bars just once, then use the two alternatives for the 1st & 2nd time round. 
You can extend this to 3rd, 4th etc if necessary.

Comment: I think the question is about how to handle a variation in the second measure of the phrase, not the last measure.

Comment: You can still use 1st and 2nd endings for this purpose. Place a copy of Bar 1 and Bar 2A before the repeat. Place a copy of Bar 1 and Bar 2B in the first ending. Put the rest of the song in the second ending.

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for.  It needs to play Bar 1, 2A, 3-9 then play Bar 1, 2B, 3-9.
What you suggest will play Bar 1, 2a, 1, 2B, 3-9 which is incorrect.
I have what you have minus the repeat bar (which is at bar 9), I was looking for a way to skip 2B on the first playback, it correctly skips 2A on playback #2 (of course).

Comment: Just put the repeat after bar 9, with two alternative bar 2's, 1st & 2nd repeat. "it correctly skips" makes me think you have a machine playing it... a human would grok it straight away.