# Is the volta ONLY used to mark unique end of a section or can it mark unique verse content within a section?

Tags: notation, musical-forms, repeats

I have a three verse, two chord song:

Verses 1 and 2 are

```
a b c
a b c
d d e
```

Verse three is

```
a b c
a b c
a f g
d d e
```

Without writing everything serially, within a repeated section with lyrics listed as:

- verse 1.  Initial blah, blah blah tah dah
- verse 2.  Similar blah blah blah, tah dah (that follows melody)
- verse 3.  More of blah blah and inserted deed dee dee, then tah dah

What marks do I use to show the unique structure of V1 and V2, vs V3?
Do I use volta 1 2, volta 3, within the section?

Answer (score 4):

## Most standard approach

The most straightforward thing to do is to use one volta for the "normal" verse, and one volta for the "extended" verse.

```
|: a b c a b c || Volta 1 & 2 = d d e :|| Volta 3 = a f g d d e ||
Verse 1 lyrics    V1 lyrics cont.
Verse 2 lyrics    V2 lyrics cont.
Verse 3 lyrics                            V3 lyrics cont.
```

[image: Notated version of above roadmap]

## Less standard approach

Another option if the "inserted" section is short would be

```
Play 3x
|: a b c a b c [3rd x only: a f g] d d e :|
```

In the score, it would look something like this:

[image: Example of score with "3rd x only" indication.]

This is risky, however, as it's prone to confusion or mis-reading. It could be combined with a "to 'location'" mark to help clarify. This is loosely what pit musicians do, for example, when marking cuts in their scores. The cleanest options would be "to 'rehearsal letter'" (as below) or "to 'measure number'".

[image: 3x only with 1,2x to sign]

## Special case

When only a small number of measures is involved, an ossia could be used.

[image: Insertion via ossia staff]

Comment: I was hoping that there was some mark, similar to volta, that says, play this, the 1st and 2nd verse, but insert this for verse three.  But for the 4 extra bars, it is straight forward.  But to have no special marks, it goes out to seven or eight pages. Not a problem in the ether, but harder to publish.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertLang Understanding this context changes my answer. I'll update in a couple of hours.

Comment: Aaron.  That may work.  It looks like you used a closed volta bar and text as instruction to the player.  I am a novice so ask, is that correct?  Permitted?  No one will seek me out to beat silly for doing that?  If so, we are good.  Let me rewrite my work.  Is there a way to post it for review?  Thank you (unless that is not permitted by the rules).

Comment: @RobertLang There's not really a standard way to do what you're looking to do, but this bracketed approach is common enough. Yes, it's a closed volta plus text. No one will beat you silly, but you might get questions from anyone who hasn't encountered something like it before. If you'd like your work reviewed, post it in [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium), which a chat room devoted to that purpose.

Comment: Your first solution is good. The “3rd x only” option is just asking for trouble.

Comment: The bracket in the second option should be open on the right side

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Wouldn't that imply that everything after the bracket would be third time only?

Comment: @Aaron 
- Hmm, maybe. But a closed bracket usually implies an end of some sort, that is if you follow the logic expressed in this post: [When should the last ending bracket(volta) be closed and when should it be open?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/113831/when-should-the-last-ending-bracketvolta-be-closed-and-when-should-it-be-open)

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I'd be happy for your opinion on the "3rd x only" bracket option as well as the third "ossia" option I've added.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for asking, I find the 3rd x only bracket and forward DS to be irregular and prone to confusion and misinterpretation. I don’t believe I’ve seen a forward DS in the past. Regarding pit musicians, yes they make cuts when necessary but it is very rare to have a show book with road maps so cuts in that genre are straightforward. Your final solution is actually not bad. I wouldn’t want to encounter it sight reading but it’s the clearest solution short of just writing out the section entirely.

Comment: I've seen manuscript dance band arrangements with mixed forward and backwards DS and DSS markings. They were horrible! It would make more sense to use a coda symbol for a forward DS, even if it is not a real coda. Coda and double coda signs can be nasty too, but at least you have an idea which way to look.

Comment: @Peter I've updated with what I think is a better solution, using a rehearsal letter or measure number.

Comment: @Aaron,  I agree this is probably the cleanest way to do it. If bar numbers are used it would be helpful to ensure the number is actually printed, not like bar 77 when only 75 and 80 have printed numbers.