# How to indicate that a part of the song should be repeated only the second time around?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, transcription, repeats

I have a song that I am transcribing, and it has a verse that repeats.
The verse starts at the very beginning of the song and is 12 measures long.
The second time the verse is played, it is played with 2 extra measures inserted in the middle of it.

Is there a way to write the notes of the verse only once, and indicate that those 2 measures should be played only the second time it is played?

Comment: You could try something like the second option in [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/120963/is-the-volta-only-used-to-mark-unique-end-of-a-section-or-can-it-mark-unique-ver/120964#120964). But it's certainly not standard notation.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using a first and second voltas, the first is the first verse, the second is the addition to the verse, and at the end of the addition I put a D.S. al Coda, put the sign where I wanted the verse to continue and at the end of the verse I put the coda sign that led to the end of the song.
It sounds messy but it worked and it doesn't look that bad.